# What is the difference between matlab impz and scipy impulse2

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, filtering

I am doing some testing with filters in python. Already done it in matlab. When doing so I get different results for the same filter when using impz in matlab and scipy.signal.impulse2 in python.
Matlab impz:
[image: Here is the result of the matlab filter]
And this is the result of the python implementation.
[image: python implementation]
To have the same I use this in both matlab and python for filter coefficents.

```
b = np.array([0.0335718093676408, 0, -0.0671436187352817, 0, 0.0335718093676408])
a = np.array([1,-1.74768237925094,2.19561759706246,-1.29097205253115,0.553269889688682])
```

And matlab code for doing this is just (this also creates the plot in matlab livescript):

```
impz(b,a)
```

The python code I have used is this:

```
T, yout = scipy.signal.impulse2((b,a))
```

and plot with:

```
plt.plot(T, yout)
```

I cant find anything in the docs that says that these should behave so differently

Comment: Show how you define the arrays in MATLAB too, just in case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`impz` and `impulse2` are not the same function. `impz` deals with discrete time systems while `impulse2` deals with a continous time system, the equivalent to `impz` is actully [`dimpulse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.dimpulse.html#scipy.signal.dimpulse) with a dt of 1.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

b = np.array([0.0335718093676408, 0, -0.0671436187352817, 0, 0.0335718093676408])
a = np.array([1,-1.74768237925094,2.19561759706246,-1.29097205253115,0.553269889688682])

T, yout = scipy.signal.dimpulse(system=(b,a,1))

plt.stem(T.flatten(), yout[0].flatten())
plt.show()
```

[image]